# PHP to insert values into SQL table

Tags: php, sql, sql-insert

So I am having this issue where i am getting the values from the POST, but when the insert query runs nothing is showing in the database, but I am getting no errors and the echos work.  Here is my files:

config.php:

```
<?php

$host = "000webhost.com";
$user = "a9257*****";
$pass = "*****";
$db = "a9257*****";

$connect = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db, $connect);

?>
```

Here is my submit.php:

```
<?php

include "config.php";

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

$insert = 'INSERT INTO tblUsers (userFirstName, userLastName, userEmail, userPassword) VALUES("'.$fname.'","'.$lname.'""'.$email.'","'.$pass.'")';

mysql_query($insert);

echo $fname;
echo $lname;
echo $email;
echo $pass;

?>
```

Any help will be much obliged.

Comment: You're using the wrong mysql library. ext/mysql is deprecated.

Comment: `mysql_query($insert) die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());` and it will show errors.

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors?  You don't seem to be checking for errors coming back from MySQL.  Given that your code is ***wide open*** to SQL injection attacks, just about anything could be happening in that query.

Comment: @ErmanBelegu don't you need "**or** die"?

Comment: You should use single quotes for the string literals in your query. Double quotes are accepted by mysql but you could have problems when migrating to another rdbms.

Comment: This is not an answer but you are very much advised to not use the mysql library as it is deprecated and instead go for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). These also support prepared statements which protects against sql injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$insert = 'INSERT INTO tblUsers (userFirstName, userLastName, userEmail, userPassword) VALUES("'.$fname.'","'.$lname.'","'.$email.'","'.$pass.'")';`

You forgot a comma `"'.$lname.'"HERE"'.$email.'"`

Edit: escape your variables or your database will get hacked (will, not if ;) )

Comment: Word.. I just saw the problem and gave an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You get no errors because you are not asking MySQL to give them to you!

Change this line:

```
mysql_query($insert);
```

into this version:

```
mysql_query($insert, $connect) or die("MySQL error:". mysql_error($connect));
```

Let us know the error, or fix it directly yourself.

AND PLEASE ADD ESCAPING! All your values allow for SQL injection attacks!

And please do not use MD5 for password hashing! Starting at PHP 5.5 there are easy to use password hashing functions, that also have been backported to PHP 5.3.6. Please include this simple library: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat